# Realsense SR300 depth streaming

Tags: ros, realsense, realsense-camera, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
anyone can get the depth stream from this 3D camera over ROS?
For me it works perfect using the original Intel library tools/example, but in ROS i just can get the RGB stream using this package 
`https://github.com/BlazingForests/realsense_camera` 
Im using ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.4 4.2 kernel 
 Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232975/realsense-sr300-depth-streaming/) by [dottant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20666/dottant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2016-04-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-13**:
Hey, what is the intel library tools/example? Are you referring to this link[1]?(https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A possible solution:
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/656

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0